# Vue component props without value

Tags: properties, attributes, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to set an attribute on my component without any value. For example:

```
<my-button primary>Save</my-button>
```

I'm declaring `primary` in `props` of my component:

```
Vue.component("my-button", {
  props: ["primary"],
  template: "<button v-bind:class='{primary: primary}'><slot></slot></button>"
})
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The `primary` property is `undefined` and the class is not applied.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/g3jkscna/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The key is to declare type of the prop as `Boolean`:

```
props: {
    primary: Boolean
}
```

Then specifying only attribute name makes its value set to `true`.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/gfa7gkdb/

Comment: Credits to [@Mottokrosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1244894/mottokrosh) as he originally posted this solution in a laracasts discussion:
 [Props without values (think attributes) in Vuejs](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/props-without-values-think-attributes-in-vuejs).